# Foundation 6 block-grid of non equal height elements

Tags: html, css, grid, zurb-foundation, block

In foundation 6 block-grid, how can one make a grid of non equal height elements that is placed immediately after their parent.

Example (image)
[image: Non equal height block-grid]
So all the bottom grey blocks moves up to where the orange blocks are, instead of being on their own **newline**

```
<div class="row small-up-1 medium-up-6 large-up-4">
    <div class="column column-block f1" style="height: 100px;">
        <div>
            <h1>block 1</h1>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column column-block f1" style="height: 250px;">
        <div>
            <h1>block 2</h1>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column column-block f1">
        <div>
            <h1>block 3</h1>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column column-block f1" style="height: 175px;">
        <div>
            <h1>block 4</h1>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column column-block f1">
        <div>
            <h1>block 5</h1>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column column-block f1">
        <div>
            <h1>block 6</h1>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column column-block f1">
        <div>
            <h1>block 7</h1>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If this is not possible in foundation, is their than anyone who can advice towards a technique that does allow this?

Thanks in advance to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Foundation's block grid, I advise using [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/). Here's a [guide on how to implement it with Foundation](http://zurb.com/university/lessons/make-a-masonry-grid-responsive), but note this is Foundation 5 so your syntax for the block-grid classes will be slightly different.

Alternatively you can use CSS Columns to achieve a similar effect, utilising the `column-gap` property. [Full example here](https://codepen.io/AdamBlum/pen/fwrnE).

```
.parent {
    column-gap: 30px;
}
```